# Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In index.js while parsing file: App.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, babeljs

I am trying to do a Crud with MySQL + Express + ReactJS + NodeJS.

I have done the backend part and its working fine i.e. NodeJS + MySQL + Express. Now I need to embed react in it. So, I have done some code and trying to compile it using "browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] src/App.js -o build.js" but I am getting the error as mentioned in my Question Title. Please let me know where I am doing wrong?

I have tried changing my Package.json from the online solution but still the problem exist.

Package.json

```
 {
  "name": "react-tutorial",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "@babel-preset-react": "^7.0.0",
  "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
  "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
  "babelify": "^10.0.0",
  "react": "^16.8.6",
  "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
  "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
  "webpack": "^4.31.0",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
  "production": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
   ]
  }
 }
```

App.js

```
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

 var App = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
  return <div>Something something Dark Side</div>;
 }
 });

 ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
 );
 export default App;
```

Index.js

```
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import './index.css';
 import App from './App';
 import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));    

 serviceWorker.unregister();
```

.babelrc

```
{
 "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />

<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

<title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>

</body>
```